# Using type object to bind object properties in C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've been coding in c++ for 3-4 years now, but I'm pretty new to C#. Thinking I can pick up quite easily and figure it out for myself with the help of online tutorials, I started working on asp.net/C# projects for my workplace... but C# has so many things that just confound me, I think I'm going to have to go pick up a book and start reading C# fundamentals.

In the meantime, I was hoping to find out the reason behind this statement, because I just simply don't understand it:

/*Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication. entry is type DirectoryEntry*/

object obj = entry.NativeObject;

What is the point of doing this? A simple, clear explanation will suffice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 'managed' library (System.DirectoryServices) to utilize the 'DirectoryEntry' class and the likes.

But, in this case, its just a facade over the original "COM" (unmanaged) objects. Sometimes it's desirable to directly talk to the 'old COM object' instead of the 'managed' .Net wrapper class.

the .NativeObject property will have the IUnknown/IDispatch interface pointer to the COM object.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I should have mentioned that "obj" isn't referenced again throughout the underlying function call (meaning it goes out of scope..so this just confused me even more). I researched "COM" and discovered it is used to bring a bunch of different GUIs from different resources into one big user interface.
You mentioned "the .NativeObject property will have the IUnknown/IDispatch interface pointer to the COM object.", so are you saying that statement affects the right operand?? This goes against all my programming beliefs xD

Comment: So it now points to the COM object, "obj", so it can use it's base class members more easily? Why would you want to "dumb" down an object's inheritance? It seems like it would be really stupid to now have the ability to: entry.NativeObject.(object members), especially because its already inherited those members, just like all types, and can already use them efficiently? I came from a C++ background and this just makes no sense to me. Thanks for your help though, I'm definitely a little less confused